# Flutter - Tracking Transparency dialog is not working

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode, dart, tracking

I have been using app_tracking_transparency in order to get permission for showing ad purposes. However, dialog is not showing. Even allow tracking function is not visible in settings of app.  I did what is written as it is written in example section of the library documentation. Furthermore, in some devices it is sometimes showing, but sometimes not showing. My whole code is:

`````
  const MyApp({super.key});

  static FirebaseAnalytics analytics = FirebaseAnalytics.instance;
  static FirebaseAnalyticsObserver observer =
  FirebaseAnalyticsObserver(analytics: analytics);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {

  String _authStatus = 'Unknown';

  @override
  void initState() {
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized().addPostFrameCallback((_) => initPlugin());
    super.initState();
  }

  Future<void> initPlugin() async {
    final TrackingStatus status =
    await AppTrackingTransparency.trackingAuthorizationStatus;
    setState(() => _authStatus = '$status');
    // If the system can show an authorization request dialog
    if (status == TrackingStatus.notDetermined) {
      // Show a custom explainer dialog before the system dialog
      await showCustomTrackingDialog(context);
      // Wait for dialog popping animation
      await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2));
      // Request system's tracking authorization dialog
      final TrackingStatus status =
      await AppTrackingTransparency.requestTrackingAuthorization();
      setState(() => _authStatus = '$status');
    }

    final uuid = await AppTrackingTransparency.getAdvertisingIdentifier();
    print("UUID: $uuid");
  }
  Future<void> showCustomTrackingDialog(BuildContext context) async =>
      await showDialog<void>(
          context: context,
          builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
            title: const Text('Dear User'),
            content: const Text(
              'We care about your privacy and data security. We keep this app free by showing ads. '
                  'Can we continue to use your data to tailor ads for you?\n\nYou can change your choice anytime in the app settings. '
                  'Our partners will collect data and use a unique identifier on your device to show you ads.',
            ),
            actions: [
              TextButton(
                onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
                child: const Text('Continue'),
              ),
            ],
          ));

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => ThemeProvider(),
      builder: (context, _) {
        final themeProvider = Provider.of<ThemeProvider>(context);
        return GetMaterialApp(
          navigatorObservers: <NavigatorObserver>[MyApp.observer],
          title: appBarName,
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          themeMode: themeProvider.themeMode,
          theme: MyThemes.lightTheme,
          darkTheme: MyThemes.darkTheme,
          home: const SplashScreen(),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}````
`````

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are using Apple id whose age in lower than 18.
Check [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=For%20users%20with%20child%20accounts%20or%20who%20are%20under%20the%20age%20of%2018%20by%20birth%20year%2C%20signed%20in%20with%20their%20Apple%20ID*&rlz=1C5CHFA_enIN1000IN1000&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Otherwise you can try this package [permission_handler 11.1.0](https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler). And Do not forgot to add in `Podfile` as `Info.plish` as well.

**Podfile**

```
 ## dart: PermissionGroup.appTrackingTransparency
     'PERMISSION_APP_TRACKING_TRANSPARENCY=1',
```

**Info.plist**

```
<!-- Permission options for the `appTrackingTransparency` -->
<key>NSUserTrackingUsageDescription</key>
<string>appTrackingTransparency</string>
```